# how to get the description of the event or Job?

Tags: mysql

I am using the Win XP as os. I Want to see the description of the event or Job.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
show events from your_database
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
SHOW CREATE EVENT <event_name>;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.events;
```